# NodeJS + Mongoose: Updating all fields on a Mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building out an api using Node, MongoDB and Mongoose. One thing that is bugging me is that you can't seem to set multiple fields at once:

```
app.put('/record/:id', function(req, res) {
  Record.findById(req.params.id, function(err, doc) {
    if (!err) {
      doc.update(req.params);
      doc.save();
...
```

However, it seems that you have to work out the update query and run it on the Model object rather than on the document object. Unless you want to assign individual properties and run save() at the end.

Is there any way of accomplishing this without having to write a Mongo query?

Answer (score 12):

jsaak's answer is good but doesn't work for nested objects.  I elaborated on his answer by searching and setting nested objects.

I added these functions to a utility.js file

```
var _ = require('underscore');

exports.updateDocument = function(doc, SchemaTarget, data) {
    for (var field in SchemaTarget.schema.paths) {
       if ((field !== '_id') && (field !== '__v')) {
            var newValue = getObjValue(field, data);
            console.log('data[' + field + '] = ' + newValue);
            if (newValue !== undefined) {
                setObjValue(field, doc, newValue);
          }  
       }  
    }
    return doc;
};

function getObjValue(field, data) {
    return _.reduce(field.split("."), function(obj, f) { 
        if(obj) return obj[f];
    }, data);
}

function setObjValue(field, data, value) {
  var fieldArr = field.split('.');
  return _.reduce(fieldArr, function(o, f, i) {
     if(i == fieldArr.length-1) {
          o[f] = value;
     } else {
          if(!o[f]) o[f] = {};
     }
     return o[f];
  }, data);
}
```

implement as:

```
var util = require('./utility');

app.put('/record/:id', function(req, res) {
  Record.findById(req.params.id, function(err, doc) {
    if (!err) {
      utils.updateDocument(doc, Record, req.params);
      doc.save();
    ...
```

Comment: In hindsight, you don't need to use underscore's lib for .reduce

Comment: I had been trying to update one item in an array of objects. For some reason the markModified method would not work.  Your method worked great.

Comment: Thanks @justin! You make my day! Great answer, @james should be marked it as 'correct answer'.

Your answer have solved my problem updating nested objects. I only have one annotation to it. You are defining 'util' as the variable which contains your methods and, afterthat, you are using it as 'utils'.

Comment: Thanks,It is awsome but i have to ask one question if the field consists of updatedDate then i have to update the date also in schema by updatedDate= new Date() then how to do it and where to add this in utility.js file

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this has changed since this question was first asked, but you can update multiple paths in Mongoose with the `set` method ike:

```
// object
doc.set({
  path  : value,
  path2 : {
    path  : value
  }
});
doc.save();
```

#### References

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set

Answer (score 8):

direct updating is not recommended according to this document:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

i solved it like this:

```
  Book.findOne({isbn: req.params.isbn}, function (err, book){
     if (err) {
        res.send(422,'update failed');
     } else {
        //update fields
        for (var field in Book.schema.paths) {
           if ((field !== '_id') && (field !== '__v')) {
              if (req.body[field] !== undefined) {
                 book[field] = req.body[field];
              }  
           }  
        }  
        book.save();
     }
  });
```

Comment: Works perfect, i made a generic function of this to use everywhere:

Comment: Works great until you have nested objects.  justin has the more complete method.

Comment: imagine the case when a field is expressly left empty ( cleared ), it wouldn't be updated with your code, and the old value would be kept.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update the entire document , you can delete the document based on its id and store the entire object again. 
That object must contain data for each and every fields of the mongo document.

Here is an example.

```js
mongoDBCollectionObject.findOneAndRemove({ // -- it will delete the entire document
  _id: req.body.fieldsdata._id  // here fiedsdata is exact copy with modification  of previous data
  }, function(err, data) {
  var newFieldsData = new mongoDBCollectionObject(fieldsdata); //-- fieldsdata updated data
  newFieldsData.save(function(err, data) { // save document to that collection with updated data
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else
        res.json({
          success: true
          });
    });
  })
```

Comment: Could you provide some example, hints or documentation to do this?

Comment: @dakab : i have update the post with example code.You can refer it.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the question, it looks like you are taking the Request parameters and using those to find *and* update the given document.

> Is there any way of accomplishing this without having to write a Mongo query?

The obvious answer is to update the Model object with the value from the Request. Which is what you suggest...

> Unless you want to assign individual properties and run save() at the end.

But it seems like you don't want to do this? It sounds like you want to update the Model object directly from the Request object?

You can do this if you really want. You just loop through `req.params` and set the `doc` values where appropriate.

```
for(var i in req.params) {
  if(req.params[i] != doc[i]){
    doc[i] = req.params[i];
  }
}
```

It should be as simple as this. However, you *only* want to do this if you have a whole bunch of validation code on the Model objects. The whole point to the Model is that you don't want to get random data in the DB. The line above will generically "set" the correct values, but you'll definitely need to include code for authentication, authorization and validation around that simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

try to updating the collection without the find, like this

```
Record.update({_id:req.params.id}, {$set: { field: request.field }}, {upsert: true}, function(err{...})
```

The option upsert create the document if not exist.

Comment: I surprised!,  mongoError: maximum call stack exceeded problem solved with your solution

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a new object and want to update whole object in the database, you can update multiple fields at once like this:

1. find the object
2. get all schema paths (fields)
3. save the new object.

```js
SomeModel.findOne({ 'id': 'yourid' },function (err, oldObject) {
 if (err) return handleError(err);

 // get all schema paths (fields)
 SomeModel.schema.eachPath(function(path) {

     // leave __id and __v alone
     if (path != '_id' && path != '__v') {
      // update the data from new object
      oldObject[path] = newObject[path];
     }
 })

 oldObject.save(function(err) {
  if (err)
  console.log(err)
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat and clean approach would be using `async` `await` and `findOneAndRemove` along with `create` Here is the sample code

```
try {
            let resp = await this.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body._id });
            let entry = await this.create(req.body);

    } catch (err) {

    }
```

**Don't Forget to mark this whole function as** **`async`**